# Sage: How to plot points along the graph of a function f(x) at specific values of x?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, graph, point, sage

If I have a 2-D plot of a function `f(x)`, like this:

```
f(x) = sin(x)
show(plot(f, (x,0, 2 * pi)))
```

Using Sage, how do I draw points along the graph of `f(x)` at specified values of `x`? For example, how would I display red dots on top of the graph above so that it looks like the graph below?

[image: graph of sine function with red dots at specific points on graph]

Given a list of values `L= [0, pi/8, pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi]`, is there a concise way to draw points on the graph of `f(x)` at each of these values of x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot a list of points, use `points` or `point2d`. See:

- [SageMath documentation for 2D plotting](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/plotting/sage/plot/plot.html)

Note that you can also customize the ticks on the axes
to match the points you are plotting.

Here is an example.

```
sage: f(x) = sin(x)
sage: xx = [0, pi/8, pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi]
sage: yy = [f(x) for x in xx]
sage: xy = list(zip(xx, yy))
sage: f_plot = plot(f, (x, 0, 2*pi), ticks=(xx, yy), tick_formatter=(pi, None))
sage: f_dots = points(xy, color='red')
sage: p = f_plot + f_dots
sage: p
```

Save the plot using `p.save`:

```
sage: p.save('plot_sin_with_points.png')
```

[image: Plot sine curve with some points]

To make the points larger, use `size` (the default size is 10).

To set the order of layers of the graphic elements in a sum,
use `zorder`.

For example one could define `f_dots` as follows instead of the above:

```
sage: f_dots = points(xy, color='red', size=30, zorder=20)
```

and get larger red dots, sitting "on top" of the curve instead of "underneath".